# Creating a non-thread safe shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm working on a mult-threaded program, but have a UI component that makes extensive use of std::shared_ptr to manage elements. I can guarantee that only one thread will ever use these shared_ptrs.

Is there a way to define a shared_ptr that doesn't incur the overhead of thread safe reference counting?

It could be based on boost::shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr.

EDIT: Thanks for answers mentioning intrusive_ptr. I neglected to mention that I also need weak_ptr functionality so that rules it out.

UPDATE: The answer for me is to use local_shared_ptr from Boost. See comment from 'he rambled'

Comment: is the overhead really that bad?

Comment: Agreed. The overhead is so minimal, that it shouldn't be the bottleneck. If you're having a bottleneck somewhere, it's not in shared_ptr.

Comment: @inestical: for this case you're probably right, but don't forget that shared_ptr allocates it's refcount on the heap. Doing that a million times might cause serious overhead. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628081/shared-ptr-horrible-speed

Comment: @stijn I would presume the allocation of the actual object stored by the shared_ptr would still take longer than allocation of the reference count. But yes, if you do it a million times it becomes an issue.

Comment: That's what `make_shared` is for.

Comment: The allocation of the reference count on the heap is necessary to make `shared_ptr` _work_; it has nothing to do with being thread-safe. The idea is that each `shared_ptr` has a pointer to this refcount. Without that, then the pointer objects can't share a reference, and it stops being a `shared_ptr`. The thread-safety in `shared_ptr` comes from the use of atomic types and atomic tests/increment/decrement operations. These are quite fast.

Comment: @Nicol: "These are quite fast" - on platforms that support such operations natively. On some platforms (such as older ARMs), they can be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: There are times where the code could be copying tens of thousands of shared_ptrs so the overhead of the interlockedincrement (or equivalent) could make a difference.

Comment: For the record, now boost has `local_shared_ptr` which does not have thread safety guarantee and also works with `weak_ptr`.

Comment: 'he rambled' thanks that's the answer! If you enter that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now adding this as the accepted answer. Boost local_shared_ptr is a single thread reference counted smart pointer that uses non-atomic operations for speed:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#local_shared_ptr

Comment: local_shared_ptr looks fantastic, except I don't see how this works with weak_ptr? It seems that creating a week_ptr around a local_shared_ptr and then calling lock() will return an actual shared_ptr, not a local_shared_ptr... and therefore presumably negating any benefit of the local_shared_ptr if most uses are weak_ptrs.  

What am I missing here?

Comment: Good point! In my code the weak pointer is only used occasionally and the shared_ptr from lock() is only used within the scope of one function. As you point out if your code usages weak_ptr extensively and then retains the result of lock() then the benefits are lost. Hopefully, they'll add a local_weak_ptr.

Answer (score 6):

Andrei Alexandrescu talked about implementing your own single threaded shared pointer class (with some additional optimizations) at the CppCon 2014

See the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qq_WaiwzOtI)

And the slides [here](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Optimization%20Tips/Optimization%20Tips%20-%20Andrei%20Alexandrescu%20-%20CppCon%202014.pdf)

I really think the standard or boost should supply a template parameter for using atomic ref counting in their shared ptrs though...

Answer (score 3):

you could use [intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html), as it allows you to provide your own reference counting. If that reference counting is a simple increment/decrement of a variable you probably won't get any better performance than that.

Comment: Thanks, but I need weak_ptr functionality too

Answer (score 1):

I have code where the overhead of copying `shared_ptr` has become an issue, and have used alternative techniques at that point.  Let me first qualify that other comments are correct that the overhead of a `shared_ptr` is very low. I profiled this to actually find one of my trouble points. On my AMD64 Phenom calling a function that copies the `shared_ptr` takes about 12ns versus calling the same function with a normal pointer at around 1ns.

With those numbers in mind it is hard to imagine you'll get any kind of "safe" variant between a raw pointer and the `shared_ptr`. So what I do in this cases I either pass the actual pointer or a `const &` to the `shared_ptr`. Usually I put a mutex lock on the whole section of code so that I'm guaranteed to maintain the shared_ptr for the entire duration. You *could* hand-roll a single-threaded reference count, but what would be the point if you know it isn't being shared?

But consider the timings very carefully. Unless you are copying the `shared_ptr` thousands, or even tens of thousands, of times per second you won't notice the overhead of the shared_ptr.

In the GUI code on the same project I always use a shared_ptr, only the server code avoids it in a few key areas. There are just so many other things in the GUI that slow it down: avoiding shared_ptr would make no appreciable difference.

Comment: Yes, I do have a situation where thousands of shared_ptrs could get copied hence in the interest in removing thread safety

Comment: "You could hand-roll a single-threaded reference count, but what would be the point if you know it isn't being shared?"  Presumably  it *is* being shared, just not by multiple threads incrementing/decrementing concurrently.  Right, there wouldn't be any point in this question otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going with the Boost intrusive smart pointer.

There is also an implementation from Scott Meyer (here: http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/M29Source.html) as published in '[More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)'

However, in case it helps, I yanked a simple refcounting pointer (with <strike>some support for polymorphic assignments</strike> and custom deletors). *This one is decided unthread-aware*.

> <sub>Note: I misremembered that. The polymorphic asignments were in a variation for antoher project. I have that too but it doesn't support the custom deletor :) Let me know if anyone's interested; Of course it comes with separate unit tests for the feature</sub>

It comes with Unit tests (e.g. to check for the famous `remove linked list node` ordering bug). So you know what you get :)

```
/*
 * counted_ptr - simple reference counted pointer.
 *
 * The is a non-intrusive implementation that allocates an additional
 * int and pointer for every counted object.
 */
#ifndef COUNTED_PTR_H
#define COUNTED_PTR_H

#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" bool mtx_unit_test_countedptr();

namespace MtxChess {

/* For ANSI-challenged compilers, you may want to #define
 * NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES or explicit */

template <class X>
    struct FreeMallocPolicy
    {
        static void do_free(X* p) { if (p) ::free(p); p = 0; }
    };

template <class X>
    struct ScalarDeletePolicy
    {
        static void do_free(X* p) { if (p) delete p; p = 0; }
    };

template <class X>
    struct ArrayDeletePolicy
    {
        static void do_free(X* p) { if (p) delete[] p; p = 0; }
    };

template <class X,class _P=ScalarDeletePolicy<X> > class counted_ptr
{
public:
    typedef X element_type;

    explicit counted_ptr(X* p = 0) // allocate a new counter
        : itsCounter(0) {if (p) itsCounter = new counter(p);}
    ~counted_ptr()
        {release();}
    counted_ptr(const counted_ptr& r) throw()
        {acquire(r.itsCounter);}
    operator bool() const { return 0!=get(); }
    void clear() { (*this) = counted_ptr<X>(0); }
    counted_ptr& operator=(const counted_ptr& r)
    {
        if (this != &r) {
            auto_release keep(itsCounter);
            acquire(r.itsCounter);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator<(const counted_ptr& r) const
    {
        return get()<r.get();
    }
    bool operator==(const counted_ptr& r) const
    {
        return get()==r.get();
    }
    bool operator!=(const counted_ptr& r) const
    {
        return get()!=r.get();
    }

#ifndef NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES
//  template <class Y> friend class counted_ptr<Y>;
    template <class Y> counted_ptr(const counted_ptr<Y>& r) throw()
        {acquire(r.itsCounter);}
    template <class Y> counted_ptr& operator=(const counted_ptr<Y>& r)
    {
        if (this != &r) {
            auto_release keep(itsCounter);
            acquire(r.itsCounter);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template <class Y> bool operator<(const counted_ptr<Y>& r) const
    {
        return get()<r.get();
    }
    template <class Y> bool operator==(const counted_ptr<Y>& r) const
    {
        return get()==r.get();
    }
    template <class Y> bool operator!=(const counted_ptr<Y>& r) const
    {
        return get()!=r.get();
    }
#endif // NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES

    X& operator*()  const throw()   {return *itsCounter->ptr;}
    X* operator->() const throw()   {return itsCounter->ptr;}
    X* get()        const throw()   {return itsCounter ? itsCounter->ptr : 0;}
    bool unique()   const throw()
        {return (itsCounter ? itsCounter->count == 1 : true);}

private:
    struct counter {
        counter(X* p = 0, unsigned c = 1) : ptr(p), count(c) {}
        X*          ptr;
        unsigned    count;
    }* itsCounter;

    void acquire(counter* c) throw()
    {   
        // increment the count
        itsCounter = c;
        if (c) ++c->count;
    }

    void release()
    {   
        dorelease(itsCounter);
    }

    struct auto_release
    {
        auto_release(counter* c) : _c(c) {}
       ~auto_release() { dorelease(_c); }
        counter* _c;
    };

    void static dorelease(counter* itsCounter)
    {
        // decrement the count, delete if it is 0
        if (itsCounter) {
            if (--itsCounter->count == 0) {
                _P::do_free(itsCounter->ptr);
                delete itsCounter;
            }
            itsCounter = 0;
        }
    }
};

} // EON

#endif // COUNTED_PTR_H
```

Unit tests (compiles as standalone)

```
/*
 * counted_ptr (cpp) - simple reference counted pointer.
 *
 * The is a non-intrusive implementation that allocates an additional
 * int and pointer for every counted object.
 */

#include "counted_ptr.hpp"
#include "internal.hpp"
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace MtxChess { 

    namespace /*anon*/
    {
        // sensed events
        typedef std::map<std::string, int> Events;
        static Events constructions, destructions;

        struct Trackable
        {
            Trackable(const std::string& id) : _id(id) {    constructions[_id]++; }
            ~Trackable()                               {    destructions[_id]++; }
            const std::string _id;
        };

        typedef counted_ptr<Trackable> target_t;

        bool testBehaviour()
        {   
            static const counted_ptr<Trackable> Nil = target_t(0);
            bool ok = true;

            constructions.clear();
            destructions.clear();

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  destructions.size());

            target_t a = target_t(new Trackable("aap"));

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    constructions["aap"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  destructions.size());

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0,    constructions["noot"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 2ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  destructions.size());

            target_t hold;
            {
                target_t b = target_t(new Trackable("noot")),
                         c = target_t(new Trackable("mies")),
                         nil = Nil,
                         a2 = a;

                MTXASSERT(ok, a2==a);
                MTXASSERT(ok, nil!=a);

                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 3ul,  constructions.size());
                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    constructions["aap"]);
                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    constructions["noot"]);
                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    constructions["mies"]);
                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0,    constructions["broer"]);
                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 4ul,  constructions.size());

                MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  destructions.size());

                hold = b;
            }

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1ul,  destructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0,    destructions["aap"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0,    destructions["noot"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    destructions["mies"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 3ul,  destructions.size());

            hold = Nil;
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 3ul,  destructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0,    destructions["aap"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    destructions["noot"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1,    destructions["mies"]);
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 4ul,  constructions.size());

            // ok, enuf for now
            return ok;
        }

        struct Linked : Trackable
        {
            Linked(const std::string&t):Trackable(t){}
            counted_ptr<Linked> next;
        };

        bool testLinked()
        {   
            bool ok = true;

            constructions.clear();
            destructions.clear();
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  destructions.size());

            counted_ptr<Linked> node(new Linked("parent"));
            MTXASSERT(ok, node.get()); 
            node->next = counted_ptr<Linked>(new Linked("child"));

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 2ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 0ul,  destructions.size());

            node = node->next;
            MTXASSERT(ok, node.get()); 

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 2ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 1ul,  destructions.size());

            node = node->next;
            MTXASSERT(ok,!node.get()); 

            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 2ul,  constructions.size());
            MTXASSERT_EQ(ok, 2ul,  destructions.size());

            return ok;
        }

    }

} // EON

int main()
{   
    using namespace MtxChess;

    bool ok = true;
    ok = testBehaviour() && ok;
    ok = testLinked() && ok;

    return ok?0:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need weak_ptr functionality too

Answer (score -1):

Boost provides a macro you can define that will not use thread-safe reference counting.

Comment: Isn't that a build time thing? i.e. build the boost library with non thread safe ref counting. I need thread safe ref counting elsewhere in the same code base.