# Performance critical alternative to share_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a `std::share_ptr<player> players[N]` global fixed size array shared among k worker threads, loading / writing done atomicaly.
I need an alternative to `std::share_ptr`, it's slow!

Comment: Please provide evidence and a use-case.  A [mcve] would be nice.  If you have done timings please post the code and compilation options.

Comment: Do you mean `std::shared_ptr`? How is it slow?

Comment: Ok, gonna post some code late this day, Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you want, you could try `boost::intrusive_ptr` , or you could [roll your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792011/alternative-to-boostshared-ptr-in-an-embedded-environment), also consider if you really need shared _ownership_, it doesn't seem like it from your example but we I guess we don't know what you really want this for.

Comment: you can try [this one](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/lightptr.hpp).