# Overhead and implementation of using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Short introduction: I am working on multithread code and I have to share dynamically allocated objects between two threads. To make my code cleaner (and less error-prone) I want to explicitly "delete" objects in each thread and that's why I want to use `shared_ptr`.

**First question:**

I want to know if implementation of `-> operator` in `shared_ptr` has some extra overhead (e.g. larger then `unique_ptr`) during run time. Objects I am talking about are usually longlife instances copied only once after creation (when i distribute them between threads), then I only access these objects' methods and fields.

I am aware, that `shared_ptr` only protect reference counting.

**Second question:**

How well are `shared_ptr` optimized in libstdc++? Does it always use mutex or take advantage of atomic operations (I focus on x86 and ARM platforms)?

Comment: In a good implementation of `shared_ptr`, there should be zero overhead when dereferencing the pointer via `->`.  I am not familiar with libstdc++, so I cannot answer your second question.  You have the headers, though, so you can easily find out by taking a look at how it's implemented.

Comment: If the code is multithreaded, GCC's shared pointer uses an `std::atomic<int>` or something like that for the reference counter; whether that's a true hardware (lockfree) atomic depends on the compiler version -- I believe this was improved in GCC 4.7.0.

Comment: Copy/assignment/going out of scope has extra overhead because of the threadsafe increment of the refcount. `operator->` looks exactly the same as the one of good old `auto_ptr`, i.e. can be expected to be zero overhead.

Comment: This question in its current form is too broad to be answered. There are many implementations of `shared_ptr`, and there are many versions of GCC and libstdc++. Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **First question**: using `operator->`

All the implementations I have seen have a local cache of `T*` right in the `shared_ptr<T>` class so that the field is on the stack, `operator->` has thus a comparable cost to using a stack local `T*`: no overhead at all.

> **Second question**: mutex/atomics

I expect libstdc++ to use atomics on x86 platform, whether through standard facilities or specific g++ intrinsics (in the older versions). I believe the Boost implementation already did so.

I cannot, however, comment on ARM.

*Note: C++11 introducing move semantics, many copies are naturally avoided in the usage of `shared_ptr`.*

*Note: read about correct usage of `shared_ptr` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628081/shared-ptr-horrible-speed/3630487#3630487), you can use references to `shared_ptr` (`const` or not) to avoid most of the copies/destruction in general, so the performance of those is not too important.*

Comment: in answer you attached it is said to use `make_shared`. I wonder how to use this template on constructor's initialization list? Example, class `Foo` has field `shared_ptr<int> num`, so constructor should look like this: `Foo::Foo(void) : num (move (make_shared (new int (30)))) { ... }`?

Comment: @Goofy: no, with `make_shared` you do not perform the `new` explicitly and on the other hand you need to pass the type of the created object explicitly; also the call to `move` is unnecessary on a temporary. Therefore it yields: `Foo::Foo(): num(std::make_shared<int>(30)) {}`

Comment: Ok, great :) I am still getting used to rvalues in C++ ;)

Answer (score 13):

GCC's shared_ptr will use no locking or atomics in single-threaded code. In multi-threaded code it will use atomic operations if an atomic compare-and-swap instruction is supported by the CPU, otherwise the reference counts are protected by a mutex.   On i486 and later it uses atomics, i386 doesn't support cmpxchg so uses a mutex-based implementation. I believe ARM uses atomics for the ARMv7 architecture and later.

(The same applies to both `std::shared_ptr` and `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.)

Comment: How does GCC know whether the code is/will be multi-threaded or not?

Comment: @DrewNoakes - you have to tell it with a #define.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I've done a little searching and can't find one.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely is one of the implementers of libstdc++. Though, I would also find it nice if you could elaborate it a bit more, like what is the define, what is default?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15129263/24874) references `BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS`, but I'm wondering if there's a version for `std::shared_ptr` as well.

Comment: There is no `#define`. Libstdc++ uses functions which dispatch (at run-time) to an atomic implementation or a non-atomic implementation based on whether the program is linked to `libpthread` or not. If it is linked to `libpthread` then it's assumed that multiple threads exist and the atomic impl is used. If not linked to `libpthread` then the program is single-threaded and so the non-atomic impl is used.

Comment: There is some brief documentation at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#std.util.memory.shared_ptr in the "selecting lock policy" section