# Is shared_ptr<void>::reset() lock-free?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, lock-free

Imagine the following:

```cpp
// SECTION A
MyClass* object = new MyClass();
std::shared_ptr<void> sharedObject;

// SECTION B (sharedObject is empty)
sharedObject.reset(object);
```

Is section B lock-free for **an empty** `sharedObject`? Or does it depend of the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on implementation.

Some pointers:

1. [Overhead and implementation of using shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902227/overhead-and-implementation-of-using-shared-ptr/10916540#10916540)
2. [Linking pthread disables lock-free shared_ptr implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470061/linking-pthread-disables-lock-free-shared-ptr-implementation)