# std::thread creation with class member function - best practice

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let's say we have some Class `SomeAlgorithm`, that has been initialized with a bunch of data and other variables. We now want to use its member function `execute` to start computing. Let's create a `std::thread`and `join` it with the main thread.

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class SomeAlgorithm {
public:
    void execute();
private:
    // variables, eg. std::vector<int> data
};

int main() {
    // (1)
    {
        SomeAlgorithm a1;
        std::thread t1(&SomeAlgorithm::execute, &a1);
        t1.join();
    }
    // (2)
    {
        SomeAlgorithm* a2 = new SomeAlgorithm();
        std::thread t2(&SomeAlgorithm::execute, a2);
        t2.join();
        delete a2;
    }
    // (3)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<SomeAlgorithm> a3(new SomeAlgorithm());
        std::thread t3(&SomeAlgorithm::execute, a3.get());
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

What is the preferred way to create such a thread? Are there any best practices?
And what is the savest way in terms of memory use that ensures that the allocated memory gets freed?

Comment: `SomeAlgorithm a1();` isn't what you think it is, so I'd start by fixing that. And `a1.~SomeAlgorithm();` is a recipe for disaster. Assuming you fixed the first problem, do you think that's the only time the destructor for `a1` will fire? Then, it's a matter of opinion (with the fast majority being anything *but* manually managing memory via operators `new` and `delete`. The "safest" way to memory management is to not actually do it yourself; Use automatics and orchestrate your code around managed lifetime to manage resources.

Comment: i fixed it, sorry just wrote the code as example, didnt test it

Comment: I wouldn't explicitly call a destructor where just limiting the scope is enough.

Comment: @Kit. outside of placement-new management, I cannot think of a time I would *ever* manually fire a destructor. And I avoid placement-new scenarios like the plague, so that problem somewhat solves itself =)

Comment: @Kit. sure, edited the code.

Comment: (1) is preferred (3) isn't valid anyway, but even if fixed, I prefer (1) above anything else. Of course that's imho, and like a lot of things, everyones got one of those.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for your opinion! I did not test the code, how do i need to fix example (3) to make it work? Also, why do you prefer (1)?

Comment: `std::thread t3(&SomeAlgorithm::execute, a3.get());` - I prefer (1) because it is by far the simplest. It isn't going to always be appropriate (if the type were *huge* and therefore not appropriate for automatic storage, a smart pointer scenario could be viable like (3)). Unrelated, `a3.reset()` is superfluous; it's going to happen anyway as soon as that scope closes. Removing that, you'll see just how similar (1) and (3) really are; only the locale of existence differentiate the two (automatic vs. automatic-managed dynamic).

Comment: @Nic I've updated my answer with some important info about `unique_ptr`. Please check it out.  `a3.get()` is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use (2). This has nothing to do with threads. Never use explicit `new`. Smart pointers if you need owning pointers.

As for (3) in your example you don't need pointers. You would need if the thread outlived the scope of the object, e.g.:

```
std::thread t3;
{
    auto a3 = std::make_unique<SomeAlgorithm>();
    t3 = std::thread{&SomeAlgorithm::execute, std::move(a3)};
}

t3.join();
```

Also there are some issues with your code. Use `make_unique`. There are some subtle bugs that can creep without it. As I've said, never use explicit new. But most importantly, don't use `get()` as it nullifies the whole point of the smart pointer.

As for (1) I would personally prefer:

```
// (1)
{
    SomeAlgorithm a1;
    std::thread t1{[&]{ a1.execute(); }};
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: `get()` is totally fine if you have to pass the pointer down a call chain, while the smart pointer is still alive. Otherwise you either have to move it (with `unique_ptr`) or you have time to inc/dec the ref count constantly (`shared_ptr`). See also [my question about passing shared_ptr to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610494/passing-const-shared-ptrt-versus-just-shared-ptrt-as-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Normally (at least for me) it's (1) in the form:

```
{
    SomeAlgorithm a1;
    std::thread t1([&a1]() { a1.execute(); });
    t1.join();
}
```

(3) is only used if you really want to disown the object from your main thread. Such as, for example (from C++14 on):

```
{
    auto a3 = std::make_unique<SomeAlgorithm>();
    std::thread t3([a{move(a3)}] { a->execute(); });
    t3.join();
}
```

It may show your intent more clearly (if you don't care about the actual results in the main thread), but it is less efficient, mostly because of cross-thread heap allocation/deallocation.

(2) is just a deprecated (since C++11) way of doing (3).