# Remove Visual Studio global mutex lock for Standard C++ Library in Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I use std::map in my code, but in debug builds code that uses it runs unacceptably slower than in release. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832511/492336) says that this is because

> In the Microsoft Visual Studio, there's a global lock when accessing
>   the Standard C++ Library to protect from multi threading issue in
>   Debug builds.

But it doesn't elaborate on a way to disable that global mutex lock. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is generally that your debug build is slow using STL, I would try turning off iterator debugging. As far as I know, that's one of the big slow downs between release and debug builds. I believe the relevant `#define` is:

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't because some of the debug checking inside the runtime library is probably (and most likely can't be made) thread safe and thus in order to give you the additional checks, you have to have the global lock.

From experience I know the debug runtime is considerably slower but in a lot of cases, the additional runtime checks are valuable. I would also point a profiler at the code before blaming the runtime - your debug code is running unoptimized unless you tweaked the flags and as a result any performance problem in the code with be magnified because the compiler did what you told it to do :).

That said, one option that you might be able to use to work around this if you are willing to forego the additional runtime checks would be to try and build your debug version against the release runtime. I haven't tried that in quite a while but the last time I tried this did work and it might make an unacceptably slow piece of code more bearable.